# Advanced Custom Fields display specific category wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories, advanced-custom-fields

I'm coding a wordpress website, but i've run into some problems. 
I have through Advanced Custom Fields make a new post type with a category. 
I want to display a specific category in my wordpress loop, but for some reason it will not work.

```
<?php
$args=array(
'post_type' => 'medlem',
'cat' => 4,
);

$medlem = new WP_Query($args);
<?php if ( $medlem->have_posts() ) : while ( $medlem->have_posts() ) : $medlem->the_post(); ?>
```

It just display all categories, which is not the meaning. Some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that your Custom Post Type have registered to "category" taxonomy type?
What do you mean by 'I have through Advanced Custom Fields make a new post type with a category.', because ACF is for creating custom fields to existing post types.

I think you could try this code:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'medlem',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'terms' => 4
    )
)
);
```

As 'field' => 'term_id' is default you can skip this line. 
For more information go to: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Of course i've made the post type and taxonomoy with the Custom Post Type UI plugin.
But thanks, your code works fine. But it is necessary with 'field' => 'term_id'?

Comment: As 'term_id' is default, you can skip 'field' => 'term_id' in your code. You can also query by 'field' => 'slug' if you want